# Student/Beginner Summer Projects

Tags: projects, learning, education

Summer is coming up and I need some projects! I've taken the only 'sound design' and 'computer tech music' courses at my university, so unless I decide to pursue a specialty school after I finish my undergrad, I'm on my own to learn more.

This summer, I'll have some time. What's the best way to spend it to learn more and become a better designer?

I have a few books, a Zoom H4n, and I'll have access to some Rode shotgun mics and a decent tascam. Game mods? Online courses? Software to learn? Problems to solve? Record 100 sounds?

I've done some digging for internships but they are nonexistent in my state and scarce outside from what I can find, especially with little to no experience.

Answer (score 2):

Depends on your interests. Game mods are pretty easy to find and join, because you can do that using the internet. There are also a few sites where you might look for short film projects. It might not be useful to work on sound libraries though, unless you're particularly interested in them or have ideas for something extraordinary, because you'd be spending a lot of time on the library, rather than working on projects and meeting new people. In any case, I would suggest anything that gets you to know people from your own field and from other relevant fields (people working on films, people working on games, people working on TV, people working on anything to which you want to/could contribute to).

Don't bother digging for interships in other ways than actually meeting with people in person. It doesn't pay off and most people and studios aren't simply bothering to advertise about internships that they could offer, but it's more like "Oh you're a good guy and you're interested in what we do. We'll let you work and learn with us.".